# Why React PWA refetch lazy load chunks based on routes when offline

Tags: reactjs, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

I am trying to do PWA with CRA and SWR for data fetching, so I did

```
serviceWorker.register();
```

then created minifist.json file.

and I did lazy loaded some components based on the routes.
so When I tried to test the offline flow on the browser by changing the url through Reach Router Link while opening the network tab, cause the app to re-fetch the component's chunk which failed - cuz offline status -, therefore causing the Error Boundary to trigger an error.

**hint : I did visit the page, before becoming offline so the chunk should have been fetched.**

<strike>secondly, how could I add a custom offline page with CRA and PWA?</strike>

**Update:**
Here's the code for handling the error cases.

```
export const dev = axios.create({ ...config.dev });
// useSWR fetcher function.
export const fetcher = (url: string) =>
  dev
    .get(url)
    .then((res) => res.data.data)
    .catch(
      (err) => err?.response?.data?.message || err.message || err?.data?.message
    );

axiosRetry(dev, {
  retries: 3,
  retryDelay: (retryCount) => {
    return retryCount * 1500;
  },
});
```

I did add the fetcher function globally at the top level

```
   <SWRConfig
        value={{
          fetcher,
        }}
      >
    ...
  </SWRConfig>
```

and within the component that using useSWR,

```
 const { data: actions, error }: any = useSWR(url);

  if (error)
    return (
      <h3 className="title">
        Opps, {error} please try again later
      </h3>
    );
```

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: @PouyaJabbarisani , no I have not, do you have any suggestion to try ?

Comment: Do you want to show custom offline page in case of user is offline? If that is the case then the first problem which you have mentioned become irrelevant.

Comment: @VimalPatel , So far no, I am using SWR for fetching data, so what I want is to show the last fetched data, which is happening, but after like a 5 second, the page refetched the chunk again, therefore the app crash.

Comment: Looks like your service worker is updating in background that's why it is refetching the chunk again.

Comment: Can we please provide the URL of your application?

Comment: @VimalPatel , Here's the link: https://ecom-dev.bonat.io 
it's a dev env, and here're the credentials, 
email: mostf0011@gmail.com 
pass: test123 
to mock the same behavior, visit the home screen after login, 
the visit any other link, then do offline and return back to the home screen,

Comment: what does your pwa configuration looks like

Comment: @Ifaruki , 
The default configuration of CRA.

Comment: Are you using useSWR react hooks for data fetching? The issues seems to be related to that.

Comment: @VimalPatel , Indeed, I am using useSWR, 
so is it impossible to use a combination of PWA and useSWR ?

Comment: How are you handling errors in that hooks in case of failure, can you share sample code?

Comment: @VimalPatel , I've just added it within the question's body.

Comment: Insted of "(err) => err?.response?.data?.message || err.message || err?.data?.message" can you assign a blank array and try it out.

Comment: @VimalPatel ,the same error has showed up.
I was looking to a way to stop fetching from useSWR in case of offline connection, but did not find anything relative.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224507/discussion-between-vimal-patel-and-mustafa-alfar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed, the issue is occurring maybe due to some code logic in one of your main component and not related to lazy loading at all.
If you check your console then you will see below error. This error is causing the application to fail.

```
TypeError: b.map is not a function
    at Auth App Page.180ff7f0.chunk.js?__WB_REVISION__=cdce21b6ef032b90bc09:1
    at Ko (react-dom.production.min.js:153)
    at Ma (react-dom.production.min.js:175)
    at ms (react-dom.production.min.js:263)
    at cu (react-dom.production.min.js:246)
    at su (react-dom.production.min.js:246)
    at Zs (react-dom.production.min.js:239)
    at react-dom.production.min.js:123
    at scheduler.production.min.js:19
    at Hi (react-dom.production.min.js:122)
```

Once you fix this issue your application will work as expected.